# Doctest error with simple case

Tags: python, doctest

With

```
def show(a):
    """ Shows a string

>>> show(a)
a

"""
    print(a)

def test():
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

if __name__ == '__main__': test()
```

I am getting an error while trying to learn how a docstring works. 
Both this method and running it from command line with

```
python -m doctest unittest.py
```

ends with errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/liquid/workspace/MyPythonProject/src/unittest.py", line 19, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': test()
  File "/home/liquid/workspace/MyPythonProject/src/unittest.py", line 16, in test
    import doctest
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/doctest.py", line 2105, in <module>
    class DocTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestCase'
```

Why?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you named your module the same as the one containing TestCase. Rename `unittest.py` to `myunittest.py` and see if it works.